# Is there a way to use the native tf Attention layer with keras Sequential API?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, attention-model

Is there a way to use the native tf Attention layer with keras Sequential API?

I'm looking to use this [particular class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention). I have found custom implementations such as [this one](https://github.com/codekansas/keras-language-modeling/blob/master/attention_lstm.py). What I'm truly looking for is the use of this particular class with the Sequential API

Here's a code example of what I'm looking for

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_length,
                          EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                          weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(100))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Attention()) # Doesn't work this way

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: I implemented an attention layer for Keras (found [here](https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras)). I've only tested this for seq2seq models. But should be able to get it working for your model (probably with some minimal changes).

Comment: Thank you thrushv89. But I'm not quite sure your link uses the Sequential API, I think it uses the Functional API, but I'm a bit of a beginner so I might be wrong

Comment: You are correct to a certain extent. I am not using the Sequential API. So if this is what you're after probably my code won't help. I am using the SubClassing API to create the layer. I am using the functional API to demonstrate the model with the AttentionLayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom class I found on [this repository](https://github.com/tsterbak/keras_attention/blob/master/models.py) by tsterbak. It's the AttentionWeightedAverage class. It is compatible with the Sequential API
Here's my model for reference :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_length,
                    output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                    weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True)))

model.add(AttentionWeightedAverage())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Note that it's what is called "soft attention" or "attention with weighted average", as described in ["Show, Attend and Tell: Neural Image Caption Generation with Visual Attention"](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/xuc15.pdf). The details are more understandable [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/attention-in-neural-networks-e66920838742)